# Enabling Advanced Google Service in Apps Script for Google Drive API - Does it cost anything?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

I need to enable the Advanced Drive Google service in order to be able to use Google Drive API. I need it because, only with this API, can I share Google Drive files programatically without sending emails to the users.

When enabling Advanced Google services, I'm asked to agree to the Google Cloud Platform and Google APIs Terms of Service.  My question is, "Do I expose my account / my company, to costs by enabling advanced Google services?" I just want to use Google Drive API to make use of one method only.

Comment: There is no cost to enabling the Google Drive API.

Comment: @AlanWells - I'd recommend adding your comment as the answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no cost to enabling the Google Drive API for use with Apps Script.
Use of the Google Drive API doesn't have a cost associated with it.

There are three quota limits for the Drive API, which are controlled through the Google Cloud Platform, not through Apps Script.  It's highly doubtful that you'll hit those limits.  The limit for Queries per day is 1 Billion.  But even if you did hit a Drive API quota limit, there is no cost, the API would just stop working.

To be charged for any API, you'd need to enable billing and set up a billing account.  It's good to understand the liability before making a commitment.  If you ever decide to pay for a service, make sure that you know how to shut it off.  There should be tools to keep track of how much of a quota that you've used.

If you hit the storage limit in your Google Drive, then you can "upgrade" to a higher storage limit, which would cost you something.  Users with personal (free/consumer) accounts can pay for more Drive storage with a product named Google One.

If you have a Google Workspace account, then extra storage can be purchased also, but it's different than Google One.

There are Cloud Computing Storage products that *do* cost something, but they probably have a free tier.

Comment: Thank you very much. So what is the reason that advanced google services are not enabled by default?

Comment: The "built-in" DriveApp service covers the needs of many users, without the need for any set-up.  Many Apps Script users have little or no experience coding, and the built-in services provide an easier way to get started than creating a standard GCP project and enabling the Drive API.  For programmers who needed more, the advanced services provide a way to program without using `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)` to make REST requests to APIs.  I can only guess at why Google did it this way.  It's probably partly the way things evolved, combined with the need to balance ease of use and capability.

Comment: Once again - thank you Alan for answering my question.